# Block users that write offensive answers

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, offensive

I reviewed an answer on this question [How to best position Swing GUIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143287/how-to-best-position-swing-guis/32182945#32182945) that said:

> its because u have a small p***s

<sup>**Warning:** spoiler</sup>

What can you do with this answer? I have flagged it as rude or abusive and added this comment:

> it is not respectful for other people! Where is your respect for other people? People like you must be blocked on stackoverflow!

Now I was thinking I need to do more. Can you block that user on Stack Overflow?

Comment: You flag it as *rude or abusive* and leave it to moderators to handle.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, I know that I have done it

Comment: @Luïs and if it happens enough, he will be contacted, possibly banned.

Comment: Commenting in such cases is likely to be the reaction they're looking for.

Comment: I'm with TZHX here -- you're only feeding the troll by commenting. Refrain from doing that next time, it's not like you have anything to prove concerning your internal plumbing.

Comment: @TZHX and FrédéricHamidi: I understand it. Next time I don't give a comment

Comment: Be aware that SO has a help center which answers most of these questions. In this case a simple search for "offensive" returned me the help page on flagging as the first hit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging . Searching for "rude" returns the same result.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sounds like [flag_ellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flagellation) is the way to go with these posts

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: If it's internal, then that is indeed pretty small and I guess the troll has a point.

Comment: @Jean-François, true, I probably should have said *internal plumbing details*. Or maybe I used *internal* as in *private to the assembly* :)

Comment: Can you edit someone else's deleted answer? I want to fix the missing punctuation...

Comment: There needs to be an option to close a Meta question with "Duplicate of FAQ".

Comment: I've seen things you people wouldn't believe... but I've never seen _"small p\*\*\*s"_ on SO and I've seen 10s of thousands of answers. Flagging works.

Comment: [Don't feed the trolls](http://blog.codinghorror.com/what-is-trolling/)

Comment: Are you joking? Did a user really did this? Answered with "small pingas"?

Comment: Calm and relax, and press flag button peacefully.

Comment: @Malavos: no it's not a joke. He said really "small p***s". (but not masked)

Comment: I'm trying to understand this level of trolling - waste time on such technical site to waste it with such low level trollin'. It seems even comical, albeit unbelievably... because of that.

Comment: @TinyGiant don't feed them, [eat them instead](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a0jCv.png)

Comment: @gnat: help... ;)

Comment: @gnat: That is hilarious.

Comment: @TinyGiant note community ad at sidebar, it is as if it senses the topic

Comment: @gnat: Ha, I didn't see that the first time around. I can't stop laughing.

Comment: The trend on Stack Overflow to censor presumed offensive terms *in citations* is childish and off-putting. I know it’s company policy but *seriously*.

Comment: @gnat "How do I troll SE?" and "How do I destroy SE?" are clearly questions for meta, suggest migration next time ;) Also, is this blue ad of UX.SE on the right coincidental or is it actually content based?

Comment: Think of such posts not like "Oh, this hurts my feelings", but like "Wow, cool, I can flag it! One more small step towards the [Deputy badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy)!"

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Please flag such a post with the *rude or abusive* option. We'll take it from there.

Moderators can warn or suspend accounts or even delete the account if there has been no positive contributions.

In this case, it was just a troll account, and it has been removed as such.

Comment: There is added a 2nd answer from a troll account. What can you do what this? He has 407 reputation. I've also flag it as rude or abusive, but I think this account is not easy to block because his reputation. Or am I wrong? Here is an image when the question is deleted: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6PHLm.jpg

Comment: @Luïs: it is an opinion, which is allowed here (this is a discussion, after all). You can see from the voting people don't agree with that opinion.

Comment: Except this means users have no control over their experience.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: we can't always prevent this stuff from being posted. Our community is very responsive and actual offensive content never lasts long, thanks to automated tools. It's the best we can do with user-generated content; filtering on text has huge downsides due to false-positives.

Comment: Agreed.  You moderators are few and we users are many.  My point is there are few individual liberties offered to users (ignore individuals, block comments from individuals, etc). Considering the workload, the moderators do a good job working for the common good.  I'm simply stating that giving individuals a certain level of control can also help create a better experience for everyone.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: no, ignoring / blocking features go counter to the philosophy of this site (we focus on content, not users), and is wide open to abuse.

Comment: Clearly this philosophy has limitations.  And if you are representative of the collective "moderator" then maybe this closed minded approach is part of the problem?  I don't mean to be rude, but some areas of the community are lacking:  https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: I'm well aware of that post. No, I highly doubt that blocking will resolve the sentiment described there, and the blog post is highly controversial. This isn't really the place to continue this discussion, however.